# JPA cascade not inserting foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entity classes - Order and OrderDetail. Below are code snippets of these two classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
@IdClass(OrderPK.class)
public class Order implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Id
private String customerEmail;

@Column(name="advance_order_time")
private Date advanceOrderTime;

@Column(name="amount")
private float amount;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =   CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<OrderDetail> orderDetailList;

public void addOrderDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail) {
     if (orderDetail != null) {
        if (orderDetailList == null) {`enter code here`
            orderDetailList = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();          
        }
        orderDetailList.add(orderDetail);
        orderDetail.setOrder(this);
     }
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name="order_details")
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="item_code")
private String itemCode;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("id")
private Order order;

}

public class OrderPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;

@Column(name="customer_email")
private String customerEmail;

}
```

Order object and the collection of OrderDetail objects are inserted successfully in the database but the order_id column of OrderDetail in null. Below is the code snippet.

```
entityManager.persist(kfcOrder);
```

order table has a composite key id and customer_email. This id is foreign key of table order_details of column order_id.

Please suggest a work around so that while persisting order object in database order_id of order_details table also gets saved.

Comment: Are you sure its persist and not update?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID",referencedColumnName = "id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL",referencedColumnName = "customerEmail")
})
@MapsId("id")
private Order order;
```

`optional = false` will ensure that no child can exist if parent doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried this. It is giving the following exception org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of com.orderserv.model.OrderDetail.order referencing com.orderserv.omodel.Order not mapped to a single property

Comment: I cannot join customerEmail column because no email column is present in order_details table.